# PHP json_decode for foreign characters

Tags: php, google-translate

I've got the following script which sends some text to the Google Translate API to translate into Japanese:

```
    <?php
        $apiKey = 'myApiKey';
        $text = 'Hello world!';
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=' . $apiKey . '&q=' . rawurlencode($text) . '&source=en&target=ja';

        $handle = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($handle);                 
        $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
        curl_close($handle);

        echo 'Source: ' . $text . '<br>';
        echo 'Translation: ' . $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
    ?>
```

However this returns `ä¸–ç•Œã“ã‚“ã«ã¡ã¯ï¼`

I'm assuming this is an encoding issue but I'm not sure how to solve this issue. The PHP manual says "This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings."

My question is, how do I get the returned translate results to properly display?

Thanks

Comment: show us the full json return

Comment: use this `$new_response = iconv("incoming-charset", "utf-8", $response);` it will convert content into utf-8

Comment: try adding a `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` to the beginning of your code to set your response to be in the UTF-8 charset.

Comment: @Manibharathi what does function iconv() do? I tried it and I'm not seeing anything echoed

Comment: @drew010 Thanks a lot, that did the trick! Can you place that as an answer and I'll accept that

Comment: Returns the converted string http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: @user2028856 Glad that helped, I added the answer with some explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON contains UTF-8 encoded text, but you need to tell the browser your page uses UTF-8 encoding.  Based on your output, it appears that the unicode text is being interpreted as ASCII text.

You can add the following to your PHP code to set the content type via HTTP headers:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

And/Or, you can add a meta tag within your `<head>` tags to specify UTF-8:

```
<!-- html4/xhtml -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!-- HTML5 -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag on your html header